# Proteus-Arduino: LEDs do not light up

Tags: led

[image]I'm building a small project with LEDs and an Arduino Uno board. It runs well with .hex file but no LEDs light up on Proteus (see picture.)

Please tell me what's wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the LED grounds connected to the Arduino Ground?

Comment: As I know, in Proteus not need to ground the Arduino (there is no pin for ground and power) ?

Comment: 1) Check the output voltages of the Arduino with an oscilloscope. They should be high enough (i.e. 3.3V or 5V). 2) Check the frequency of the outputs. If the frequency is high (e.g. >500Hz) then you may not be able to see them light up as they blink fast. 3) Decrease the full drive current of the LEDs. Make it like 1mA.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that the code is working as displayed by the red mark near the pins. You could **try by removing the current limiting resistor**(Not recommended on actual hardware implementation), the package you selected for the resistor could be causing you problem. If the LED lights up without the resistor, you can try later with a different resistor package.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I removed the resistor and nothing changed ... I'm thinking that the problem maybe in leds library?

Comment: Yes, Even I think so... Just check whether the current rating of the LEDs once. If they are too high, they could be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Proteus, but I checked the internet and found [this tutorial](https://www.circuitstoday.com/proteus-tutorial-led-and-bar-graph) about using LEDs in Proteus.

Proteus has various types of parts.  Only ones marked "ACTIVE" will light up or do other things in an animated simulation.

The tutorial shows this example of an LED that will light up during simulation:

[image]

Since you are simulating the output from an Arduino, you might look into the "Model Type" setting for your LEDs.  You can set it for analog or digital, with digital being recommended for use with microprocessors.

Selecting the model type looks like this:

[image]

You can also see options for the minumum time that a simulated LED will light - this can make it easier to see rapidly blinking LEDs.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations! I have tryed all things you mentioned, but leds still do not light up (on Proteus).